# wrapping a isnull around a cast - sql

Tags: sql

i have the sql line below which outputs either two numbers ( cl or cb). sometimes there is a null, when there is a null id like to output an empty string/blank.
I have tried the second line but got a conversion error but unsure how to resolve this.

```
cast (isnull(cf.cl,cf.cb) as decimal (18,4)) as  xyz

isnull((cast (isnull(cf.cl,cf.cb) as decimal (18,4))),'') as  xyz
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - both as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: `decimal (18,4)` and `''` are contradictory. Are you trying to return a column that is a string or a decimal?

Comment: It is returning a decimal but sometimes there is a null value, when there is there is no value for cl or cb, rather than output NULL i want an empty string

Comment: You have to choose, either decimal **or** character. (However, I'd go with decimal and let the presentation layer deal with nulls.)

Comment: thanks! i just managed to figure it out and the below worked -- this worked. isnull ((convert(varchar,cast(isnull(cf.cl,cf.cb) as decimal (18,4)))),'') as  "xyx"